# Opening java process with .NET

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, process

Due to my favourite game Minecraft change , it launches now differently than before but because i am not very advanced with process opening i need help.

I used to have this code:

```
Dim p = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe", "-cp " & mcroot & "bin/minecraft.jar;" & mcroot & "bin/lwjgl.jar;" & mcroot & "bin/lwjgl_util.jar;" & mcroot & "bin/jinput.jar; -Djava.library.path=" & mcroot & "bin\natives -Xmx" & xmx & " -Xms" & xms & " net.minecraft.client.Minecraft " & pseudo & " " & sessionid)
        If show_debug = "0" Then
            p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        Else
            p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        End If
```

and it worked on version 1.5.2 but now when version 1.6.2 came out it started launching it differently:

```
Running C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe -Xmx1G -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.2\1.6.2-natives-8702682110482

 -cp C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\argo\argo\2.25_fixed\argo-2.25_fixed.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.47\bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\14.0\guava-14.0.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.2\gson-2.2.2.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.0\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.0\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar;
C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.2\1.6.2.jar
net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username mjacobinc --session token:9b7c825b93004afe84ea48d3ebcc9550:5a2c380e72e04e56be0835ee47eb83dc --version 1.6.2 --gameDir C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft --assetsDir C:\Users\Kristjan\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets
```

it starts now completely different with new launcher , but because it broke my custom launcher i need it back working , can someone who has time please change up process start code to get game launched? Any help is much appriciated .

Comment: It might help if you add a VB.NET tag to this question -> while the language falls under the .Net Framework, the language itself is VB.NET.

Comment: added vb.net tag , still trying to figure this out but my brain can't take it anylonger

Comment: Have deleted my answer as you have not shown any effort or investigation into this, really, I think you should check with minecraft forum to find out....